# Finding prime number in c, my if doesnt do its job

Tags: c

I have to make a code that will find prime numbers in given interval, and the `if (y % j == 0)` wont work, why is that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    int a, b, br=0, i, j, brojac=0, y;
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b); 
    int p[b-a];
    for(i=a; i<=b; i++){
        p[br]=i;
        br++;
    }

    for(i=0; i<br; i++){
        y=p[i];
        for(j=1; j<= (int) sqrt(p[i]); j++){
           if(y%j == 0){
               printf("\n%d", p[i]);
               brojac++;
               break;
           }
        }
    }

    printf("\n%d", brojac);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `sqrt()`; use `j * j < p[i]` or thereabouts.

Comment: Please in the future codes you write, use meaningful names for your variables. It is hard to someone else read a code with variables named `y, p, a, b, br`

Comment: All numbers are divisible by one; testing with `j = 1` doesn't tell you anything useful.  Generally, end format strings with newlines; don't put newlines at the start unless you want blank lines in the output.

Comment: A little gotcha, what would be the value of `p` if `a = 5` and `b = 7`? What should it be? What about the value of `br`?

Comment: No prime number except 2 is divisible by 2: so you don't need to test even divisors. In fact, if you are building a list of primes (from 2) you only need to test with the primes already in the list as divisors.

Comment: Your p[b-a] array is not wide enough for the subsequent for loop.

Comment: It is not necessary to build an array, you can just nest the prime test within `for(i=a; i<=b; i++)`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler [or thereabouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47420566/finding-prime-number-in-c-my-if-doesnt-do-its-job#comment81795316_47420566) includes `j * j < p[i]` may overflow unlike `sqrt()`, and should be `<=`.  `j <= y/j` can do the job.

Comment: @chux:  I agree on the `<=` rather than `<`; I realized that shortly after the edit window expired and was glad for 'or thereabouts'. Under most of the plausible circumstances (ranges of values) under which this is likely to be tested, there wouldn't be an overflow, but the division is guaranteed safe.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Re: "this is likely to be tested, there wouldn't be an overflow", I agree yet consider another [unexpected overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ariane_5#Notable_launches).  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The FOR condition `j<= (int) sqrt(p[i])`. I would do a function

```
bool isPrime(int n){
  int i;
  if(n == 2)
    return true;
  if(n%2 == 0 || n==1 )
    return false;
  for(i=2; i<=n/2; i++){
    if(n%i == 0)
        return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: That is very wasteful on large numbers, and testing with even divisors is more so.

Comment: You might want to use `i * i <= n` because although your method will work as is, it becomes slower for larger primes. The goal in testing for primality is to use the fewest numbers for the test as possible

Comment: A better `for` loop would be: `for (i = 3; i * i <= n; i += 2)`.  If you tested for divisibility by 3 before the loop, then you could use: `for (i = 6; (i - 1) * (i - 1) <= n; i += 6)` and test `if (n % (i - 1) == 0 || n % (i + 1) == 0) return false;` in the body.

Answer (score 1):

Doing `for(j=1 ...` will have all numbers match `y % 1`, so start from 2.

Then your algorithm as it is will displays numbers that are *not* prime, once the problem above is corrected.

Instead, set a variable `prime` to 1, and reset it to 0 when the number is seen as not a prime. After the loop display the number if it is still flagged 'prime':

```
for(i=0; i<br; i++){
  y=p[i];
  int prime=1;  // <===== start telling it's a prime
  for(j=2; j<= (int) sqrt(p[i]); j++){ // <=== start from 2
     if(y%j == 0){
        prime = 0; // <==== Not a prime
        break;
     }
  }
  if (prime) {  // <=== after the loop, still a prime
     brojac++;
     printf("\n%d", y);
  }
}
```

Finally you might want to follow advice from the comments below your question.

Answer (score 0):

Code problems:

1. Minor: `scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);` No check for failure.
2. `br=0,... int p[b-a]; for(i=a; i<=b; i++){ p[br]=i; br++;` will eventfully attempt access 1 passed `p[]`.
3. `for(j=1; ...  if(y%j == 0){` --> `y%1 == 0` is always true.
4. `j<= (int) sqrt(p[i]);` is a poor test as `sqrt()` is expensive and a weak `sqrt()`  may return a value just under the expected whole number one.
5. `if(y%j == 0){ printf("\n%d", p[i]);` prints numbers that are not prime.
6. Logic error in `for(j=1;` loop as that loop eliminates candidate primes and should not print anything.

Too many problems.

Instead, use the fast [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void Sieve_of_Eratosthenes(int a, int b) {
  printf("Primes from %d to %d\n", a, b);
  bool prime[b+1];
  for (int i = 2; i<=b; i++) {
    prime[i] = true;
  }
  for (int i = 2; i<=b; i++) {
    if (prime[i]) {
      for (int j = i+i; j <= b; j += i) {
        prime[j] = false;
      }
    }
  }
  for (int i = a;i<=b; i++) {
    if (prime[i]) printf("%d\n", i);
  }
}

int main(void) {
  Sieve_of_Eratosthenes(7,50);
}
```

Output

```
Primes from 7 to 50
7
11
13
17
19
23
29
31
37
41
43
47
```